# What is the equivalent of Select Case in Access SQL?

Tags: ms-access, select-case

I have a query which includes fields named *openingbalance* and *commissions*. I would like to compute values for *commissions* based on *openingbalance*, similar to this `Select Case` block in Access VBA:

```
Select Case OpeningBalance
   Case 0 To 5000
        commission = 20
   Case 5001 To 10000
        commission = 30
   Case 10001 To 20000
        commission = 40
   Case Else
        commission = 50
End Select
```

But since Access doesn't allow `Select Case` in a query, how can I accomplish my goal in Access SQL?

Answer (score 94, accepted):

Consider the [Switch Function](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/switch-function-HA001228918.aspx) as an alternative to multiple `IIf()` expressions.  It will return the value from the first expression/value pair where the expression evaluates as True, and ignore any remaining pairs.  The concept is similar to the `SELECT ... CASE` approach you referenced but which is not available in Access SQL.

If you want to display a calculated field as `commission`:

```sql
SELECT
    Switch(
        OpeningBalance < 5001, 20,
        OpeningBalance < 10001, 30,
        OpeningBalance < 20001, 40,
        OpeningBalance >= 20001, 50
        ) AS commission
FROM YourTable;
```

If you want to store that calculated value to a field named `commission`:

```sql
UPDATE YourTable
SET commission =
    Switch(
        OpeningBalance < 5001, 20,
        OpeningBalance < 10001, 30,
        OpeningBalance < 20001, 40,
        OpeningBalance >= 20001, 50
        );
```

Either way, see whether you find `Switch()` easier to understand and manage.  Multiple `IIf()s` can become mind-boggling as the number of conditions grows.

Comment: HansUp you are the greatest. The switch function works great. Thanks

Comment: Is `SWITCH()` one of those VBA functions that you can only use in Access SQL *when executed from within* Access itself (like `Nz()`), or does it also work when you use the JET Red OLE-DB/ODBC or ACE driver?

Comment: Since it's [available in sandbox mode](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/functions-and-properties-in-access-blocked-by-sandbox-mode-9a829783-f7a8-4a9f-8d43-8650b8cc9565#bm2), I think it should work in any query whether or not the query is run from within an Access session.

Answer (score 9):

You can use IIF for a similar result.

Note that you can nest the IIF statements to handle multiple cases. There is an example here: http://forums.devshed.com/database-management-46/query-ms-access-iif-statement-multiple-conditions-358130.html

```
SELECT IIf([Combinaison] = "Mike", 12, IIf([Combinaison] = "Steve", 13)) As Answer 
FROM MyTable;
```

Comment: Thanks for the response RedFilter, this is perfect for another query I am working on where I only needed to combine 2 if statement. Since I just started using Access 4 months ago I think the switch function HansUp suggested is easier to read.

Comment: Very late to the party, but worthy of note: care should be taken when using `IIf` due to the fact that *all parts (test, true result and false result) are all executed during call*.  So, if you have any function calls in your `IIf`, for instance - `SELECT IIf(Process([Combinaison]) = "Mike", 12, IIf(Process([Combinaison]) = "Steve", 13)) As Answer  ...`, and those functions *change* any values, then the effect will happen twice - once for each call. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/Language/Reference/user-interface-help/iif-function#remarks

Answer (score 2):

You could do below:

```
select
iif ( OpeningBalance>=0 And OpeningBalance<=500 , 20, 

                  iif ( OpeningBalance>=5001 And OpeningBalance<=10000 , 30, 

                       iif ( OpeningBalance>=10001 And OpeningBalance<=20000 , 40, 

50 ) ) ) as commission
from table
```