# Using iif to mimic CASE for days of week

Tags: sql, ms-access

I've hit a little snag with one of my queries. I'm throwing together a simple chart to plot a number of reports being submitted by day of week.

My query to start was :

```
  SELECT Weekday(incidentdate) AS dayOfWeek
, Count(*) AS NumberOfIncidents
   FROM Incident
    GROUP BY Weekday(incidentdate);
```

This works fine and returns what I want, something like

```
   1      200
   2     323
   3     32
   4     322
   5     272
   6     282
   7     190
```

The problem is, I want the number returned by the weekday function to read the corresponding day of week, like `case when 1 then 'sunday'` and so forth. Since Access doesn;t have the SQL server equivalent that returns it as the *word* for the weekday, I have to work around.

Problem is, it's not coming out the way I want. So I wrote it using `iif` since I can't use `CASE`. The problem is, since each iif statement is treated like a column selection (the way I'm writing it), my data comes out unusable, like this

```
  SELECT 
 iif(weekday(incidentdate) =1,'Sunday'),
 iif(weekday(incidentdate) =2,'Monday')
 'so forth
, Count(*) AS NumberOfIncidents
  FROM tblIncident
   GROUP BY Weekday(incidentdate);



  Expr1000  Expr1001    count   

  Sunday              20
           Monday      106
                      120
                      186
                      182
                      164
                       24
```

Of course, I want my weekdays to be in the same column as the original query. Halp pls

Comment: Create a lookup table, which matches each of the 7 numeric values to text names, and join on it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the WeekdayName() function.

```
SELECT
    WeekdayName(Weekday(incidentdate)) AS dayOfWeek,
    Count(*) AS NumberOfIncidents
FROM Incident
GROUP BY WeekdayName(Weekday(incidentdate));
```

Comment: ............-_- I don't know why they don't list that on the weekday documentation page

Answer (score 2):

As BWS Suggested, `Switch` was what I wanted. Here's what I ended up writing

```
SELECT 
 switch(
 Weekday(incidentdate) = 1, 'Sunday',
 Weekday(incidentdate) = 2,'Monday',
 Weekday(incidentdate) = 3,'Tuesday',
 Weekday(incidentdate) = 4,'Wednesday',
 Weekday(incidentdate) = 5,'Thursday',
 Weekday(incidentdate) = 6,'Friday',
 Weekday(incidentdate) = 7,'Saturday'
 ) as DayOfWeek
 , Count(*) AS NumberOfIncidents
FROM tblIncident
GROUP BY Weekday(incidentdate);
```

Posting this here so there's actual code for future readers

Edit: `WeekdayName(weekday(yourdate))` as HansUp said it probably a little easier :)

Comment: Good, clean example of a Switch statement. Definitely usable for other CASE scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

check this previous post:

[What is the equivalent of Select Case in Access SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15774078/is-it-possible-to-using-select-case-statement-in-access-query)

Comment: `Switch` Worked. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Why not just create a 7 row table with day number & day name then just join to it?