# Performing column operations in CASE WHEN statment condition in sql query

Tags: sql-server-2008, ms-access

I'm developing an application using vb.net2008 with database as msaccess. I've designed a table in database having columns IN_TIME and OUT_TIME in format HH:MM:SS . I want a result as TOT_TIME which will display difference between these two columns. I've written a query for this, now i'm facing a problem that i dont want to display result if IN_TIME is less than 8:00:00 AM else display result. I have used CASE WHEN but it didnt worked, help me out.

I've tried this so far

```
SELECT * 
  (CASE WHEN LATE_LIMIT > '" + date3 + "' 
   THEN ROUND(([PM_OUT]-[OVERIME_LIMIT]),2) 
   ELSE 'N' )AS OverTime 
FROM DTR_REC
```

Comment: Are you Missing END i.e CASE WHEN something > something THEN something END AS something

Comment: Doesn't msacess support "WHERE  IN_TIME > '08:00:00'" as in SQL?

Comment: Is this an Access or SQL Server question? The question doesn't mention SQL Server but you tagged the post as such? Anyway Access doesn't support the `CASE` statement, so your options are to either use `IIF` or `SWITCH`. See this post for an example of how you can do this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15774078/is-it-possible-to-using-select-case-statement-in-access-query

Comment: @jpw : Ya Accesd doesnt support CASE, i tried IIF. Thanks a lot for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a comma and an END case:

```
SELECT * 
  ,(CASE WHEN LATE_LIMIT > '" + date3 + "' 
   THEN ROUND(([PM_OUT]-[OVERIME_LIMIT]),2) 
   ELSE 'N' END)AS OverTime 
FROM DTR_REC
```

But I'm not sure if Access supports CASE statements. If not does this work:

```
SELECT * 
  ,IIF(LATE_LIMIT > '" + date3 + "', ROUND(([PM_OUT]-[OVERIME_LIMIT]),2),'N') AS OverTime 
FROM DTR_REC
```

Comment: For the record, no, Access SQL does not support the `CASE [...] WHEN` construct. Possible alternatives in Access SQL are the `Switch()` and `IIf()` functions.