# IErrorInfo.GetDescription failed with E_FAIL(0x80004005)..Surendra Marri

Tags: c#, asp.net, ms-access

Below query when I execute I am facing:

> IErrorInfo.GetDescription failed with E_FAIL(0x80004005).

to Connect MS Access dataBase. When I excute same in SQL Server its working but its not working for MS Access DataBase. Can any one help on this.

```
select [EmpName],EmpMaster.EmpCodeDisplay,Transactions.CardNo,
case when CONTROLLERS.ControllerName = 'Level0Entry' then 'Reception' when CONTROLLERS.ControllerName = 'LevelBCiscoNSNRx' then 'Basement' 
else CONTROLLERS.ControllerName end as ControllerName,aDateTime from Transactions 
inner join CONTROLLERS on Transactions.ControllerNo = CONTROLLERS.ControllerNo  
inner join EmpMaster on Transactions.EmpCode = EmpMaster.EmpCode 
where transactions.ControllerNo in ('7','9') and aDateTime between '1/28/2015 05:45:00.000' and '1/28/2015 23:59:00.000' 
and transactions.EmpCode <> '0'   and Transactions.CardNo in (select CardNo from Transactions 
where transactions.ControllerNo in ('7','9') and transactions.EmpCode <> '0' and aDateTime between '1/28/2015 05:45:00.000' and '1/28/2015 23:59:00.000' 
 group by Transactions.CardNo having COUNT(Transactions.CardNo) < 2 )  order by aDateTime asc
```

Comment: That is not valid Access SQL (No `case` statement support)  If the error persists after fixing the query you need to show where in your code the error occurs; [is it possible to using select case statement in access query?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15774078/is-it-possible-to-using-select-case-statement-in-access-query)

Comment: 0x80004005 usually means access denied...

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the [**SWITCH**](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/advanced/switch.php) statement for MS Access

OR

the **[IIF](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/advanced/iif.php)**