# function with 2 parameters and nested

Tags: vba, ms-access

Table with 3000 records with 21 column fields

I need to loop thru the records using the 2 column fields (Field2 and Field3) where there are a null values to Produced a New column field (Field4)
I started with this function below but I am stuck since case select cannot accept null- or I may need to use nested iifs which I am not good at.

SampleTable

```
Name(Field1)  Parts(Field2)   Categories(Field3)  New Field(Field4)
1              A1              R1                 Inventory
2              A1              Null               Inventory
3              B1              R1                 Processing
4              B1              R4                 Processing
5              B1              Null               Unknown 
6              Null            Null               Unknown
```

My function:

```
Function MachineCheck(Field2, Field3) As String

Dim newValue As String

Select Case (Field2)
     Case "A1":
        Select Case (Field3)
            Case "R1"
                newValue = "Inventory"
            Case Is null
                newValue = "Inventory"
            Case "R1"
                newValue = "Inventory"
            Case “ “
                newValue = "Inventory"

       Select Case (Field2)
         Case “B1”
End Select

MachineCheck = newValue
End Function
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You don't have to go through the collection of records, you have to write proper query!

Comment: A query calls this function

Comment: Status: MachineCheck ([Field2], [Field3])

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to write query this way:

```
SELECT Field1 AS [Name], Field2 AS Parts, Field3 AS Categories, 
      SWITCH( Trim(Field3) & Trim(Field4) = "A1", "Inventory",
              Trim(Field3) & Trim(Field4) = "A1R1", "Inventory", 
              Trim(Field3) & Trim(Field4) = "B1", "Unknown",
              Trim(Field3) & Trim(Field4) = "B1R1", "Processing",
              Trim(Field3) & Trim(Field4) = "", "Unknown") As [Status]
FROM YourTable;
```

FOr further information, please see: [What is the equivalent of Select Case in Access SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15774078/what-is-the-equivalent-of-select-case-in-access-sql)

Comment: Thanks so much for your help- I tried using the query and this works however I have some nulls for "both fields" and this does work- I cannot see the Unknown

Comment: So, try to replace: `=""` with `Is NULL`.