# Error when trying to create case statement In MS Access

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

Getting Syntax Error( missing operator) in query expression, What am I getting wrong?

```
SELECT
    ExportUF_NEW.Position, 
    ExportUF_NEW.[User Defined Field 03]
    (CASE
        WHEN ExportUF_NEW.[User Defined Field 03] = OP THEN "Production"
        WHEN ExportUF_NEW.[User Defined Field 03] = STM THEN "Thermal"
        ELSE NULL
    END) AS OperationGroup
FROM ExportUF_NEW
    WHERE (((ExportUF_NEW.[User Defined Field 03]) Is Not Null))
```

Expect an outcome to new column "OperationGroup" based on ExportUF_NEW[User Defined Field 03].

Comment: Access does not support CASE. See the duplicate link.

Answer (score 0):

MS Access did not support CASE WHEN, use switch instead.
Similar link: [What is the equivalent of Select Case in Access SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15774078/what-is-the-equivalent-of-select-case-in-access-sql)