# Unrecognized keyword WHEN

Tags: sql, excel, vba, ms-access

```
SELECT Rating, SUM(Poids) 
FROM Test
WHERE Portefeuille = 'NameTest' AND LaDate = #20/10/2021# 
GROUP BY Rating 
ORDER BY CASE WHEN Rating = 'AAA' THEN 1 
              WHEN Rating = 'AA+' THEN 2 
              WHEN Rating = 'AA' THEN 3 
              WHEN Rating = 'A+' THEN 4 
              WHEN Rating = 'A' THEN 5 
              WHEN Rating = 'A-' THEN 6 
              ELSE 7
```

Why the above SQL String throw an error :

```
Run-time error è-2147467259 (80004005)': Unrecognized keyword WHEN.
```

Comment: If you check the online manual for Access you'll learn that it doesn't have CASE expressions. This question and answer should help you... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15774078/what-is-the-equivalent-of-select-case-in-access-sql

Comment: @MatBailie So this mean that `ORDER BY SWITCH()` Will allow me to do a custom order ?

Comment: Why ask a question you can test and answer for yourself? No matter what someone tells you, you're going to have to test it yourself anyway. (Yes, use switch.)